# How to store the value of a cell in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I want to store the value of cell [136,7] in sheet Schools in a string

```
Dim Num As String

Num = Schools.Cells(136,7).Value
```

This code won't run. I am suspecting the error occurs because I cannot refer to my sheet directly use its name. But I do not know how to remedy this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are 2 different naming systems:

1. The VBA code name of a worksheet (which can be changed in the Project Explorer in VBE)

   ```
   Num = Schools.Cells(136,7).Value
   ```
2. The tab name of the worksheet (which can be changed by any user)

   ```
   Num = Worksheets("Schools").Cells(136,7).Value
   ```

Note that `Schools` and `Worksheets("Schools")` can be 2 completely different worksheets. These 2 naming systems are completely independend.

Comment: It returns Application-defined or object-defined error when I use both

Comment: @koch You should only use one of them. Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schools")` then. Is the worksheet `Schools` in the same workbook as the code?